# Navbar dropdown menu (using bootstrap) non functional

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After following a tutorial on youtube about implementing a simple navigation menu I'm having an issue getting a dropdown menu to display and collapse two additional links. Can't seem to figure out the problem. Do I need to link to another stylesheet or .js file?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>None</title>

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <!--Fixed Navbar with dropdown -->

        <div class ="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle"collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#" class="brand"><img class="logo" src="images/om_logo_2.png"></a>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">                 
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Opportunities <b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="hgv.html">HGV &amp; Lorry Delivery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="domestic.html">Domestic Parcel &amp; Package Courier</a></li>
                                </ul>
                        </li>

                    <li><a href="#">Vehicle Hire</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

...

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors shown in the browser console?

Answer (score 0):

You are not referencing the jquery library

like in the bootstrap example [here](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

```
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like it is being referenced at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Oops. Sorry, just saw that.

Answer (score 0):

Change this..

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle"collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```

Working on Bootply: http://bootply.com/103529